# Gettting error - Node that has both node children and fragment children! Not supported by flat storage

Tags: autodesk-forge

During loading 3d model, keep getting an error:

> "Node that has both node children and fragment children! Not supported by flat storage".

Anyone know why? and how to fix this? ForgeViewer used to work without this error.

Answer (score 0):

That error has been suppressed for recent versions (v6/7) - try upgrade to later versions.

If the error persists upload the model files to GDrive/weTransfer/Dropbox and drop the link to forge.help at autodesk.com so we can reproduce and check further.